# Java Client/Server - Using BufferedWriter instead of PrintWriter

Tags: java, client-server

In all examples of a Java client/server, I've seen `BufferedReader` used for receiving data, like in

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

and `PrintWriter` for sending data, like in

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
```

But can't I just use a `BufferedWriter` instead of a `PrintWriter`? I only need to send unformatted String betweens client and server, so a `BufferedWriter` should give better performance (not that this is a problem).

Comment: I'm betting that performance differences will be minimal if any at all.  Have you tried using BufferedWriter?  There should be no problem with your using it.

Comment: The problem with BufferedWriter is that it seems to block when I call `write()`.

Comment: @Helper Method That's because it buffers the data (until its internal buffer is full) before writing it.

Comment: If you are sending down a socket with buffering, then remember that what you send won't reach the other end until either (a) the buffer is full, or (b) you explicitly call flush(). So if you've reached the end of writing a crucial "packet" of conversation that the other end needs to receive, you'll need to remember to call flush() else the other end might not get it and things will appear to hang.

Comment: @someguy: that doesn't make sense. Buffering would *prevent* the block unless the buffer is filled.

Comment: @Helper Method: *all* OutputStreams and Writers can block when writing to sockets. It's not exclusive to BufferedWriter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PrintWriter essentially provides convenience methods around a Writer. If you don't need those convenience method-- but just need to write chars-- then functionally, you can use any flavour of Writer you choose, including a 'raw' OutputStreamWriter.

If you are writing chars one at a time, and your socket stream isn't buffered, then it would be advisable to put some buffering in somewhere, either by using a BufferedWriter or by wrapping a BufferedOuputStream around your raw output stream. An example of where you don't typically need to do this is in a servlet, where the streams passed to your servlet are typically already buffered.

PrintWriter also has the "feature" of swallowing exceptions on write methods, which you have to then explicitly check for with checkError() [hands up who actually does this, and who just assumes that the write succeeded...]. This may or may not be desirable...

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can use a `BufferedWriter`. `PrintWriter` is commonly used for **conveniance** as it offers a good range of functions without the extra exception handling (which often makes the examples easier). The `PrintWriter` could also **delegate** its operations to a `BufferedWriter` if desired.

Regarding performance see the javadocs for [`BufferedWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)

> In general, a Writer sends its output immediately to the underlying character or byte stream. Unless prompt output is required, it is advisable to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write() operations may be costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, the exception swallowing makes it more likely to introduce bugs, of course. It's horses for courses...

Answer (score 2):

Whats wrong with PrintWriter? The match is made because of the convenient readLine / writeLine match. You don't have that convenience in a BufferedWriter. Also you get to specify autoflush with your PrintWriter.
If you need the buffer you can wrap the BufferedWriter in a PrintWriter

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( ... ) );
```

Comment: N.B. BufferedWriter has a newLine() method if you need it.

Comment: Yes, but bw.write( string, start, end); bw.newLine(); bw.flush(); is not really that convenient.